# How should questions about the Game Boy CPU be tagged?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The Game Boy is kind of notorious for having a CPU which few can agree how to name.  The Sharp-manufactured design is similar to the 8080 and to the Z80, but the processor is [not actually compatible with either](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/).  In the homebrew scene it is sometimes known as the GBZ80; for a while, it was also called the LR35902 after the markings on the chip itself, but that was later determined to be the name of the whole SoC package.  The latest consensus seems to be to refer to the CPU as SM83, as the design was found most similar to the one described in datasheets for the Sharp SM83xx series of microprocessors.

In light of this, what is the most appropriate tag for questions about the CPU?  I can see a couple of options:

- Use [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) or [z80](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/z80).  Since the designs are similar enough to share assembly syntaxes to an extent, questions intended for one are probably applicable to the other.  Questions about the Game Boy CPU specifically could be found with filters such as ‘8080 and game-boy’.  But the fact that 8080 and Z80 have separate tags in the first place would count against this.
- Create a dedicated tag for the CPU like [sm83](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sm83).  This seems a bit excessive given that the CPU is mostly known for its use in just one system, so in practice in would be used in conjunction with [game-boy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy) a lot.
- Use just [game-boy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy).  This would make the scope of the tag particularly broad, referring both just to the CPU and the Game Boy as a whole.

Your thoughts?  Is this worth splitting hairs over anyway?

Answer (score 1):

We could use [game-boy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy) [cpu](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu), for questions where the Game Boy CPU is specifically relevant.

Comment: A problem with such pairing would be that if you have a question about programming the Game Boy in assembly, then logically it ought to be tagged ‘[tag:assembly] [tag:game-boy] [tag:cpu]’, leaving only two tags to capture what is it that you’re trying to program (there is a maximum of five tags per question). So it seems less than ideal too.

Comment: @user3840170 If that becomes a problem, we can ask SE to raise our tag limit, because we're _graduating_. (But I don't think most questions actually run into the existing limit.) Or you can just drop [tag:cpu], because it's (practically) redundant with [tag:assembly].